# Previous records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id game_id user_id user_playing_status user_turn_status
 1       1       2                   1                1
 2       1       4                   1                0
 3       1       6                   1                0
```

How can we access previous record of current record ?

If there are three records r1,r2,r3 in table 
so previous record of r2 should be r1 , r3 should be r1 and r1 should be r3.

I use the following query

```
select user_id 
from current_playing_users 
where id < (select id from current_playing_users where user_id = 2)
```

But i am not getting previous record of first record.I want to get records in anticlockwise manner. Like in image previous user_id of 2 should be 6

Comment: what version of mysql ? No order by ?

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 0):

you could use LAG function

```
select LAG(user_id) over (order by {your desired order}) as previous_row
from ..
```

LAG function return the former cell at the desired column with a pre-defined order.

Answer (score 0):

Are looking you for the *correlated* subquery ? :

```
select cu.*.
       (select cu1.user_id
        from current_playing_users cu1
        where cu1.id < cu.id
        order by cu1.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as prev_user_id
from current_playing_users cu;
```